# Qt flow layout with scroll area

Tags: qt, pyqt

I am attempting to do a HTML style grid layout in Qt using this example here: https://gist.github.com/Cysu/7461066. It nearly does what I want, however when I put it into a scroll area it seems to collapse down to a minimum size and not want to expand to the full size of the scroll area. I did see that in the documentation you need to set the `sizeConstraint` in the layout to `SetMinAndMaxSize`, however this did not seem to fix it.

How can I get the layout to occupy the maximum size inside of the scroll area?

Here's a basic example, importing the class from the link above:

```
class App(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__():
        super().__init__()
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        
        grid = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        grid_layout = FlowLayout()
        grid_layout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetMinAndMaxSize)
        grid.setLayout(grid_layout)
        
        scroll_area = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        scroll_area.setWidget(grid)
        layout.addWidget(scroll_area)
        # layout.addWidget(grid) # adding the widget the the parent layout works just fine...
        
        for i in range(25):
            grid_layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(f"Label {i}"))
```

Comment: `scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)`

Comment: @alec Ah, well that was simple... Thanks, did the trick!